# AWS: how do I create a Network Load Balancer Target Group using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

We are creating a network load balancer using CloudFormation.  The target type is IP, and it needs to point to the IP address of a VPC endpoint.

So we need to create a target group of type "ip", and specify a list of the targets:

```
  NetworkLoadBalancerTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-NLT'
      Port: 443
      Protocol: TLS
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: 300
      TargetType: ip
      Targets: # list of the primary IP addresses of the Network interface(s) associated with the VPC endpoint
        - ?????
```

The targets need to be the IP address(es) of the VPC endpoint.  How do I reference these?

The VPC endpoint is created thus:

```
  VpcEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      VpcEndpointType: Interface
      SubnetIds:
      - !Ref ProtectedSubnetA
      - !If [IsProd, !Ref ProtectedSubnetB, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
      - !If [IsProd, !Ref ProtectedSubnetC, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref SecurityGroupHttpsInInternal
      - !Ref SecurityGroupHttpsOutInternal
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.execute-api
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      PolicyDocument: '{
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "*",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": "*",
              "Principal": "*"
            }
          ]
        }'
```

I could get the list of network interface ids like this:
`!GetAtt VpcEndpoint.NetworkInterfaceIds`

However, that's a list of strings.  How do I get the PrimaryPrivateIpAddress attribute for each network interface in the list of ids?

For completeness, here's the definition of the Network Load Balancer and associated listener:

```
  NetworkLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        - Key: load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled
          Value: true
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-NLB-Protected'
      Scheme: internal
      Subnets:
        - !Ref ProtectedSubnetA
        - !If [IsProd, !Ref ProtectedSubnetB, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        - !If [IsProd, !Ref ProtectedSubnetC, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
      Type: network

  NetworkLoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref NetworkLoadBalancerTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref NetworkLoadBalancer
      Port: '443'
      Protocol: TLS
      SslPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !Ref ACMCertificate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, that's a list of strings. How do I get the PrimaryPrivateIpAddress attribute for each network interface in the list of ids?

As you noted, `AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint` returns `NetworkInterfaceIds` and not the IP addresses. Therefore, to get the actual IP addresses you would have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

This would be in the form of a **lambda function** to which you would pass the ENI IDs. The function would use **AWS SDK** (e.g. boto3) to get the corresponding IP addresses. The function would return the IP address to CFN which would you would use in your target group.

Comment: thanks.  That's really annoying, since it will take more time than a line of YAML, but at least I know it's do-able.

Comment: @mdarwin No problem. Yes, CFN is rather limited. If you will be working a lot with CFN you will be writing custom resources for a lot of things sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I found your post searching a solution for the exactly same problem. Let me share my conclusion

Once by `GetAtt` we cannot access IP list then we need to write a CustomResource to obtain they.

As AWS suggest at this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/four-ways-to-retrieve-any-aws-service-property-using-aws-cloudformation-part-1/) I implemented a CustomResource to obtain these IPs.
Also there's a related [issue](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/109).

First we need to setup IAM Roles to lambda. Note that without these roles we'll not be allows to see logs at CloudWatch

```
LambdaRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
        Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
LambdaPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: LambdaPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - ec2:*
              - logs:*
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - !Ref LambdaRole
```

And create the lambda function that will receive that list of NetworkIds and search NetworkInterface IPs:

```
LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Condition: IsNotProd
    DeletionPolicy: 'Delete'
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import cfnresponse
          import json
          import boto3
          def lambda_handler(event, context):
              print('REQUEST RECEIVED:\n' + json.dumps(event))
              responseData = {}
              if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, {})
                return
              if event['RequestType'] == 'Create':
                try:
                  ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
                  enis = event['ResourceProperties']['NetworkInterfaceIds']
                  for index, eni in enumerate(enis):
                    network_interface = ec2.NetworkInterface(eni)
                    responseData['IP' + str(index)] = network_interface.private_ip_address
                    print(responseData)
                except Exception as e:
                  responseData = {'error': str(e)}
                  cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, responseData)
                  return
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 10
```

Then create the Custom Resource

```
GetPrivateIPs:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCEndpoint
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    Condition: IsNotProd
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
      NetworkInterfaceIds: !GetAtt VPCEndpoint.NetworkInterfaceIds
```

Finally you'll be able to access those IPs

```
Targets:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPort: 443
      HealthCheckProtocol: TCP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
      Port: 443
      Protocol: TLS
      Targets:
        - Id: !GetAtt GetPrivateIPs.IP0
          Port: 443
        - Id: !GetAtt GetPrivateIPs.IP1
          Port: 443
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```